# Stack Logic Symbols in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, stacking-symbols, logic

I want to reproduce diagrams like the following in tikz (taken from Sider's [Logic for Philosophy](http://gelogica.weebly.com/uploads/2/6/6/1/26617550/sider_logic_for_philosophy.pdf), p. 189):

[image]

In particular, I can't figure out how to stack symbols as they are in this image (having 1s and 0s above certain operators, and asterisks either above or below). I've tried stacking with `\mathop` and `\overset` but neither is producing the result I need.  Here is my current code:

```
$$\mathop{\Diamond}_{*}^{1} \Box P \rightarrow \Box \Diamond P$$ % kind of squished together and doesn't work in tikz node environment

$$\overset{1}{\Diamond} \Box P \rightarrow \Box \Diamond P$$ \\% works in tikz node but squished together and no option to put something underneath


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt]

\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=2cm] (1) [label=left:$a$] {$\Diamond  P \rightarrow \Box \Diamond P$};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=2cm]  (2) [label=left:$b$, below left=of 1] {$\Box P$};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=2cm] (3) [label=left:$c$, below right=of 1] {$\Diamond P$};

\path[->] (1) edge (2);
\path[->] (1) edge (3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: See `stackengine` package.  I think it should be straightforward.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm shocked, just shocked that you would suggest that, Steven. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking can be obtained with `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning}

\newenvironment{LfPmatrix}
 {$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{array}{*{7}{c}}}
 {\end{array}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt]

\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=1.5cm] (1) [label=left:r\strut] 
  {\begin{LfPmatrix}
    \mathtt{1}&&&\mathtt{0}&\mathtt{0}\\
    \Diamond&\Box&P&\to&\Box&\Diamond&P\\
    {*}&&&&{*}
   \end{LfPmatrix}};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=1.5cm] (2) [label=left:a\strut, below left=of 1]
  {\begin{LfPmatrix}
    {*} \\
    \mathtt{1} \\
    \Box&P
   \end{LfPmatrix}};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum height=1.5cm] (3) [label=left:b\strut, below right=of 1] 
  {\begin{LfPmatrix}
    {*} \\
    \mathtt{0} \\
    \Diamond P
   \end{LfPmatrix}};

\path[->] (1) edge (2);
\path[->] (1) edge (3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]