# Self-referring arrow in tikz for a model in modal logic

Tags: tikz-pgf, logic

I'm currently trying to typeset a model of Theodore Sider's *Logic for Philosophy* and struggle to get a self-referring loop in TikZ. The model itself was already solved in another post here: [Stack Logic Symbols in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338036/stack-logic-symbols-in-tikz). However, I'd need such loops as in this picture at the boxes c and d:

[image: Model for modal logic]

I tried to do it but my arrows all come out weird:

[image: My trials for making loops in TikZ]

And the corresponding code (I called the node of the box (4)):

```
\draw [->] (4) to [out=240,in=150,looseness=8] (4);
\path[draw=red,->] (4) to[ below, loop, out=180+70, in=180+50, min distance=10mm] (4);
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance!

A draft of the book can be found here: https://gelogica.weebly.com/uploads/2/6/6/1/26617550/sider_logic_for_philosophy.pdf

Comment: Try drawing a rectangular path with option rounded corners (see manual), assign an arrow tip. Locate it at south.west of (4). // The red curve is just a second try?

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you! And yes, the red one was a second try,

Comment: I found another solution that's working for me:
```\draw (arrow1) edge[in=-180,out=-90,scale=1.5,loop] (arrow1);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, align=center, minimum height=1.2cm] (node) at (0,0) {1\\$P$};
\draw[-{Stealth[round]}, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt] (node.south west) to[out=-90, in=180, distance=1cm] (node.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Box with looped arrow]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!